# Use AWS ES2 for Big Data Analytic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to send files from a mobile application to ES2 that has a python script file that processes the file and the final product will be save into S3?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a simple webapp in EC2 to receive the data from your mobile app, run the python script you mentioned with the data, use the S3 API and save the data there. As for how you're going to deploy that webapp, there are tons of ways/languages/technologies, fit for another question.

Comment: Is there any available tutorial to visual help me?

Comment: It's more of a concept than a specific tool you know. Think about it as 3 parts: Deploying a web app (could be python, using Flask or Django), running a script you created earlier (SO can help you with that) and later "How to save data into S3", the latter being easier to find in AWS docs. Check for tutorials for each of these topics and you're good to go.